# Как пишется суффикс "ин"?

Tags: орфография

Насчёт **ан**, **ян** и **онн**, **енн** мне уже известно. А как пишется **ин**?
Говорят, что **ин** пишется с одной буквой **н**, однако есть ещё слова за исключением: **длинный**, **старинный**, **подлинный**, **невинный** и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

В ваших словах "ин" - корневое, либо суффикс того слова, от которого образовано прилагательное. Поэтому суффикс прилагательного там просто Н. Наверное и остальные слова из того же ряда. Пишите - разберёмся.

Comment: Похоже, некоторые участники форума. судя по вопросам, пытаются в последний момент хоть как-то подготовиться к ЕГЭ. ПО-моему. лучше прямо заявить об этом, чтобы знать, кому отвечать. Нерадивому выпускнику, ребенку, только начавшему изучать грамматику и орфографию, или иностранцу. пытающемуся разобраться в нашем языке.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно смотреть не просто на сочетание букв (в слове длинный нет суффикса -ин. есть корень длин- и суффикс -Н, аналогично в слове невинный)и не просто на суффикс, а на то, с помощью какого суффикса образовано прилагательное. Голубь+ ин= голубиный, страус+ ин= страусиный и т.п. Слово старинный образовано от слова старина (в нем уже есть-ин-) с помощью суффикса Н. получилась удвоенная Н, так же, как и в слове былинный. 
Слова странный и подлинный запомните. На современном этапе там суффикс не выделяется.  Хотя с исторической точки зрения там такое же словообразование, поэтому удвоенная Н.